Looker Studio scorecard date comparison - running total
I am trying to help a colleague with comparison sales data using the scorecards on Looker Studio.
We have a scorecard showing the running total of sales for the current week. We want to show a comparison to the previous week - current week starts on a Monday -, but until it's Friday, the comparison to the previous week is not particularly useful - Looker Studio is comparing the total of a full past week with a week that hasn't ended yet.
Example for one client, taken on Mon 8th April:

Because the current week starts on the Monday, but the comparison date range is the full last week, obviously the comparison shows -90+ %.
My colleague is wondering if there is a way to create a comparison, that compares the same number of days in the previous week - so on 8th April, it would compare to the previous Monday, on Tue 9th it would compare the sum of the previous Mon and Tue, etc. until the end of the week.
I don't know if it's possible at all, the comparison date range options seem limited.
Thank you in advance!
I looked at all the options on Looker Studio - the best I have found is to compare the last 7 days rather than looking at the comparison with the current week, but it's not the same.

I thought i had a great answer for you but it only works with a week start on a Sunday or Monday, let me know if that is of use to you

hello! Yes, we are indeed looking at weeks starting on a Monday :) I have just realized that my question didn't specify that, sorry!

I have just realised that either I'm a silly goose, or Google has updated the options for the date filters - I can select This week to date, so when it compares with a previous period, it takes the same days from the previous week :) problem solved!
